# Iterating count function in cypher

Tags: cypher

I am trying to count the number of nodes that have a certain property key
I currently have:

`MATCH (a:address) 
WHERE a.countries = "Austria" 
RETURN count(a)`

to count a single node.
I would like to iterate this for a large list of property keys such as "Austria", "Denmark", "Finland" without having to manually change each key

How would I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Some remarks: (1). Your query is not syntactically valid, as `a.address` will not compile. Did you mean `(a:address)`. (2) Please format your query as source code by indenting each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to match nodes that have "Austria", "Denmark" or "Finland" in their `countries` property? Also, that is not valid Cypher.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a small example dataset:

```
CREATE (:address {name: "Vienna", countries: "Austria"})
CREATE (:address {name: "Salzburg", countries: "Austria"})
CREATE (:address {name: "Munich", countries: "Germany"})
```

To count the `address` nodes for each country, use the following query:

```
MATCH (a:address)
RETURN a.countries, count(a)
```

As Cypher is a declarative query language, you do not have to iterate on the results - the query engine does that for you. For a detailed explanation, check the documentation on [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-aggregation).

This returns:

```
╒═════════════╤══════════╕
│"a.countries"│"count(a)"│
╞═════════════╪══════════╡
│"Austria"    │"2"       │
├─────────────┼──────────┤
│"Germany"    │"1"       │
└─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Note: I am not familiar with your data model, but I think using the singular `country` would be a better choice for the attribute name.